# Is it possible to link a webdriver to a c++ program as a single executable?

Tags: c++, selenium, cmake, geckodriver

I'm making a program using selenium in c++. I was wondering if it is possible to link the webdriver to the output executable, so I wouldn't have to store the webdriver executable separately from the project executable.

Specifically, I'd like to do this with geckodriver, but it is written in rust so I am not sure if it is possible. Also, I'd prefer to do the linking with cmake if it is possible.

Comment: Off hand I'm not sure this is possible. The web driver executable actually spawns a web application that runs on localhost. Client libraries make web API calls which then control the browser.

Comment: @DebanjanB that looks interesting, I’ll try using that instead